# Difference between UserTransaction and EntityTransaction

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, jakarta-ee, jta

Title says it all: What is the difference between a [`UserTransaction`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/transaction/UserTransaction.html) and an [`EntityTransaction`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/EntityTransaction.html)?

My rudimentary understanding is that `UserTransaction` is used when JTA is required (e.g. to do queries on mulitple things), and that `EntityTransaction` is used when JPA only is required (e.g. when the query is atomic).

Is that the only difference between the two or is there more to it than that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is difference between @Resource UserTransaction and EntityManager.getTransaction()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517062/what-is-difference-between-resource-usertransaction-and-entitymanager-gettransac)

Comment: @ewernli : That's a bit unfair, I'd only know that that question was a duplicate if I already knew the answer to the question in the first place! Neither the question nor the answer make any mention of `EntityTransaction` - I did search before asking.

Comment: I completely understand that. That's also why I took the time to answer your question the best I could. It's just a common practice on SO to indicate possible duplicate so that people can read answers to both questions, it improves the quality of SO. It's not a critique or anything. The question is "closed as exact duplicate" only if there are 5 votes that mark it as such.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> My rudimentary understanding is that
>   UserTransaction is used when JTA is
>   required (e.g. to do queries on
>   mulitple things), and that
>   EntityTransaction is used when JPA
>   only is required (e.g. when the query
>   is atomic).

That's basically right, but your description of "multiple things" and "atomic" is a bit strange. JTA allows the developper to use distributed transaction to perform changes on multiples resources (database, JMS broker, etc.) atomically (all-or-nothing). If only one resource is accessed (e.g. one single database), you don't need JTA, but the transaction is still atomic (all-or-nothing). That's for instance the case when you use a regular JDBC transaction on one database.

Considering `UserTransaction` vs. `EntityTransaction`:

- If JPA is use stand-alone, you use `EntityTransaction` to demarcate the transaction yourself.
- If JPA is used within a managed environment where it integrates with JTA, you use `UserTransaction`. The `EntityManager` hooks itself into the JTA distributed transaction manager. The only subtlety I'm aware of considers the flush of the changes. When `EntityTransaction` is used, JPA know it needs to flush the changes. If transaction are controlled using `UserTransaction`, it needs to register a callback using JTA [`registerSynchronization`](http://java.sun.com/products/jta/javadocs-1.0.1/javax/transaction/Transaction.html#registerSynchronization%28javax.transaction.Synchronization%29), so that the changes are flushed to the database before the transaction completes. If you use EJB with CMT (container managed transaction), you don't even need to use `UserTransaction`: the app server starts and stops the transactions for you.

Related questions:

- [What is difference between UserTransaction and EntityManager.getTransaction()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517062/what-is-difference-between-resource-usertransaction-and-entitymanager-gettransac) (duplicate)
- [XA and non-XA datasource with Spring/Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878597/local-transaction-already-has-1-non-xa-resource-cannot-add-more-resources-erro) (related)